# 1140px grid alignment issues

Tags: css, grid

Hi I am building a gallery style site and am very interested in using the 1140px grid from cssgrid.net as I feel 960px is too small for this project.

I would like to have 3 images of four columns each in the first row, then 4 images of 3 columns each for the rest of the rows beneath.

The issue is that once I do that the right edges of the two rows don't align, and obviously the gallery won't look so good. I understand that this is caused by the rounding off due to columns being built with percentages in this grid. However it still looks bad and I'd like to have them aligned in some way. What is the solution to this?

My code for the index page here:
http://pastebin.com/c76U7J5g

To see this happening you have to download the cssgrid.net grid

[image]

Comment: Show us some code. http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: Can you post the code you're using now? It's hard to offer any advice without seeing your current implementation

Comment: I'm just looking at the default code from this grid. If you download it from CSSgrid.net and check the columns you'll see what I mean. I've also added my specific index.html code so you can see the problem more clearly.

Comment: Can you add a screen shot of the result of your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what is happening, it appears to be a simple mistake.

Your placeholder images (the cats) are too small. Using placeholder images in this grid system can be tricky because you have to declare the size you want the place holder to be. In reality, on your live page, the images won't have demensions specified because it will break the grid system (the grid will just scale down the image to the largest size that fits in the column you have put it in).

To make a long story short, the placeholder images are too small! At their full size, they won't fill up the grid spot, therefore causing the odd positioning you describe. That being said, I always put in placeholders that are at least 1000px so they can be scaled down properly.

EDIT:

Try doing what Foundation does:

```
.last {
float: right;
}
```

Add that to the stylesheet - it should align the right edges of the last columns.

Comment: I don't think that's the case because even without placeholders there still is this problem, as illustrated in the screenshot above, taken from the default code.

Comment: Ok, I see what you're saying now, but is that approximately 1-3px mis-alignment really going to matter?

Comment: In my case yes, since I'm building a gallery site and I want the first row to be three bigger images and then the next row to be 4 small ones. To me the difference is noticeable and doesn't look good.

Answer (score 2):

Percentage based layout is not pixel perfect. I have used the css framework http://www.1140px.com/ in one of my projects and I am satisfied. 
You can try it if you want pixel perfect layout.